# Liveserver doesn't work with react js in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I am using React.js with the live server plugin in VSCode and when using live server I get this page:  [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kmMX.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With react, you don't have to use liveserver. Go to your terminal and then navigate to the root of your react project and then run `npm start`.

This information is also available in the [create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/)